# Magento deployement on Nginx server

Tags: magento2, nginx, server-setup

On my local machine, apache server is installed and magento2 is working absolutely fine on it.

However it has been mentioned that nginx server is better than apache, so i tried to configure it too. For nginx installation, i changed the port and base path. And nginx server is working fine as i checked it from browser.

The next step is to install magento2 so i do that by following steps mentioned on devdocs documentation http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/install-gde/prereq/nginx.html

In order to verify the installation of magento 2 i browsed the link but couldn't get any response. I know it may be an open end question but i have tried number of solutions mentioned on internet, i am really stuck here.

It will be good if you can tell me what i have missed, or doing wrong or suggest some solution which i can try.

Thanks

Comment: there is no point to change webserver if you not sure how to debug errors. work with apache by default.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Got it working by adding the ip and web site domain to "hosts" file.

> File Path in Ubuntu: /etc/hosts

Added following line:

```
127.0.0.1   www.magento2-dev.com
```